# Pybrain creating a time-series input

Tags: time-series, sequence, pybrain

I have a snippet of code which goes like this

```
ds = SequentialDataSet(1,1)
ds.newSequence()
ds.appendLinked([a],[b])
ds.appendLinked([b],[c])
ds.appendLinked([c],[d])
```

This effectively creates a sequential data set with only ONE sequence, and from here, I can feed the data into a network with ONE input node and ONE output node.

My question is, do you reckon the data is being fed into the network ONE by ONE at different time steps which essentially creates a time-series input?

Thanks!